# How to define a state_machine in a Concern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, state-machine, activesupport-concern

I am trying to factor out some duplicated logic into a [concern](https://37signals.com/svn/posts/3372-put-chubby-models-on-a-diet-with-concerns). Part of the duplicated logic is a [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine).

Simplified, the `Database`, `Site`, `SftpUser` and more contain, amongst others, this:

```
class Database < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  state_machine :deploy_state, initial: :halted do
    state :pending
  end
end
```

I'm attempting to refactor this into a concern:

```
module Deployable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    state_machine :deploy_state, initial: :halted do
      state :pending
    end
  end
end

# Tested with:
class DeployableDouble < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend Deployable
end

describe DeployableDouble do
  let(:subject) { DeployableDouble.new }

  it "should have default state halted" do
    subject.deploy_state.must_equal "halted"
  end
end
```

However, this is not the correct way to implement a `state_machnine` in a `concern`, because this results in: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'deploy_state' for <DeployableDouble:0xb9831f8>`. Which indicates that the Double did not get a statemachine assigned at all.

Is the `included do` actually the right callback to implement this? Is it maybe an issue with `state_machine`, it needing a subclass of ActiveRecord::Base or so? Something I'm not getting? I am pretty new to the concept of Concerns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay. I am feeling really stupid. One should not `extend` a class with a module, but `include` that module. Obviously.

```
# Tested with:
class DeployableDouble
  include Deployable
end
```

One of these things that you oversee once written.  Also, extending the `ActiveRecord::Base` is not needed, since state_machine is just plain old Ruby and works on a generic Ruby Object.