# Split ActiveRecord model that uses two state machines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, encapsulation, state-machine

I have a model using two [state machines](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine)

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  state_machine :call_state, :initial => :pending do
    event :start do
      transition :pending => :started
    end

    event :restart do
      transition :started => :pending
    end

    event :finish do
      transition :started => :finished
    end
  end

  state_machine :payment_state, :initial => :unpaid  do
    event :pay do
      transition :unpaid => :paid
    end

    event :pay_back do
      transition :paid => :paid_back
    end

    event :reject_payment do
      transition :unpaid => :rejected
    end
  end

  #tons of methods related with call_state
  #tons of methods related with payment_state
end
```

I want to split this `ActiveRecord` model on three:

1. A module/class to encapsulate **definition and methods** related with `call_state`
2. A module/class to encapsulate **definition and methods** related with `payment_state`
3. A module/class to **work with both**. This third module/class could have methods like

   ```
   def can_call?
     xxx.paid? and yyy.can_start?
   end
   ```

where `xxx`/`yyy` could be a `MyModel` instance or a method in a wrapper class. I don't know...

The question is: **what is the best way to do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Use [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) to factor out your state machine as a module.

Longer version: you can look at [How to define a state_machine in a Concern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396103/how-to-define-a-state-machine-in-a-concern), where the poster answers the same question.

Hope this helps